# How to confirm that curl_global_init() has been called?

Tags: curl, libcurl

Is there a way to confirm that `curl_global_init()` has been called before?

---

In my application there are multiple third party libraries that use curl and are calling `curl_global_init()` individually. The libraries have been armed with the option to disable that call, but then I need a way to determine if the `curl_global_init()` function has been called before.

I know.. the alternate is to make a call to `curl_global_init()` myself and then just disable all the other calls. That is not the point though.

---

The [standard information page](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_global_init.html) on `curl_global_init()` does not mention any way of doing that. Also, a simple internet search doesn't yield anything of that sort either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you're right.

As of today, there is no standard way of knowing that `curl_global_init()` has been called by your application already.